# Can't reach IMM on IBM x3650 M3

Tags: ibm, imm2

I have **IBM x3650 M3 server 7979B9G**. My issue is I can't reach the IMM interface via network (can't ping , no link Act led)

I tried to configure IMM in multiple ways, but dedicated ethernet port doesn't seem to show any activity (all leds are off).
May be I need some IMM module installed? How should I check it ?

Checked LAN cable with ETH01 port:

[image]

It's working. So I used the same cable with IMM:

[image]

As you see no activity

Here's my config:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok guys, here's the answer. To work with IMM via Ethernet port you need a special card. In my case it's the IBM PowerPC 405GP Remote Supervisor Adapter

Comment: Did you discovered how to check if this card is available?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking this is a hardware issue, as you show us on the first picture when you connect the UTP on the ethernet channel, it is linking (the green light), but as you can see in the picture down, the IMM port ins't linked.

[image: image with cable IMM]

So, this is probably the port hasn't a correct behaviour, that's the reason you're not reaching the IP.